# CSS3 animation with gradients

Tags: animation, webkit, css, gradient

Is there really no way to animate a gradient-background with CSS?

something like:

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, rgb(196,222,242)), color-stop(0.5, rgb(242,242,242)), color-stop(1, rgb(240,240,240)));
  }
  50% {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, rgb(222,252,255)), color-stop(0.5, rgb(242,242,242)), color-stop(1, rgb(240,240,240)));
  }
  100% {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, rgb(196,222,242)), color-stop(0.5, rgb(242,242,242)), color-stop(1, rgb(240,240,240)));
  }
}
```

*I know, for Safari 5.1+ and Chrome 10+ there is a new gradient-syntax, but for now, I have to stick with the old one for this project.*

Comment: you can't change css or what?

Comment: ? … nothing happens if I run this animation on a element ( -webkit-animation: pulse 1s infinite; )

Comment: I think it does not work with gradients, even with new syntax

Comment: I just learnt this the hard way! transitions on a linear gradient do not work yet

Comment: transitions doesn't but transforms do, so you can translate/rotate/skew them around at least ie https://codepen.io/philipphilip/pen/OvXEaV

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Transitions are not supported yet on webkit gradients. It's in the spec, but it doesn't work yet.

(p.s. if you're doing color transitions only - you may want to check out -webkit-filters - which do animate!)

Update: gradient transitions apparently do work in IE10+

Comment: It's in the spec for the *new* syntax though, not proprietary `-webkit-gradient()` crap.

Comment: AFAIK there's no support for gradient transitions anywhere yet - even the ones that support the new syntax.

Comment: BTW, if you're willing to go SVG - then gradient transitions are just dandy - as long as you're on a recent browser. See http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/Stwelve.svg

Answer (score 9):

Put each gradient variation on it's own layer. Absolute position them.  Give each it's own set of keyframes synchronized with each other.  In those keyframes define opacity for each layer, at each keyframe, with 1 and 0 mixed around amongst keyframes.

Beware that the container's color will bleed through, so wrap the layers in a parent with a background of white.

http://jsfiddle.net/jSsZn/

Comment: That's indeed really clever — but you need additional elements only for styling (for me a no-go) and in most cases this is not possible because you relay on the gradient as a background of a element by its own. but thanks for this creative solution — right now this seems to be one of the only ways to animate — at least 'fake'-animate — a gradient.

Comment: Really clever solution here.

Answer (score 6):

I solved the problem via applicating :before attribution to the a tag.

Link: http://codepen.io/azizarslan/pen/xsoje

### CSS:

```css
nav ul#menu li a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;

    /* webkit gradient background */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(204, 0, 51), rgb(153, 0, 0));
}

nav ul#menu li a:before {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;

    /* webkit gradient background */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(0, 156, 204), rgb(0, 111, 145));

    /* webkit transition */
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms linear;

    /* before hack */
    content: ".";
    text-indent: -99999px;
}

nav ul#menu li a:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Great work around. I got it to work in IE 10 & 11 too. It's good enough fallback (no smooth transition but hover works all the same) on IE 9 but earlier versions may require a compatibility fallback if IE 8 or earlier statement.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out css sandpaper- this lets you achieve animated gradients, but it's not a pure css solution.  Css sandpaper takes care of cross-browser rendering of the gradient, and there's a piece of javascript which handles the animation.

http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/04/05/cross-browser-animated-css-transforms-even-in-ie/

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for a transition of your text from a solid color to a gradient. Just animate the rgba color of the text to reveal the background gradient applied on it.

#### CSS:

```
.button {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#fe046e), color-stop(100%,#a02ed4));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);

    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
            transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.button:hover {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#fe046e), color-stop(100%,#a02ed4));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Brian instead of using new html elements, use sudo elements :before and :after. Position the main element as relative, then position the pseudo elements as absolute with 0 for top, left, right, and bottom.

### HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

### CSS:

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

div::before, div::after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

Add your keyframes and gradients to the div and the pseudo elements using opacity. Use z-index to control which is on-top of which.