# Use CSS3 transitions with gradient backgrounds

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-gradients

I'm trying to transition on hover with css over a thumbnail so that on hover, the background gradient fades in. The transition isn't working, but if I simply change it to an `rgba()` value, it works fine. Are gradients not supported? I tried using an image too, it won't transition the image either.

I know it's possible, as in another post someone did it, but I can't figure out how exactly. Any help> Here's some CSS to work with:

```css
#container div a {
  -webkit-transition: background 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: background 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: background 0.2s linear;
  transition: background 0.2s linear;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  margin: 30px;
  z-index: 2
}

#container div a:hover {
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 100 75, 100, 100 75, 0, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, .4)))
}
```

Comment: IE10 supports gradient transitions now - it was a happy surprise !

Comment: @mkprogramming, woha, it really does and looks great! Here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VXMn5/show) (works with IE10+). Hope other browsers get support for this cool stuff too.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

This is now possible using the @property workaround. Please see [@Mahozad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63848864).

---

Original Answer:

Gradients don't support transitions yet (although the current spec says they should support like gradient to like gradient transitions via interpolation.).

If you want a fade-in effect with a background gradient, you have to set an **opacity** on a container element and 'transition` the opacity.

(There have been some browser releases that supported transitions on gradients (e.g IE10. I tested gradient transitions in 2016 in IE and they seemed to work at the time, but my test code no longer works.)

October 2018 Update: Gradient transitions with un-prefixed new syntax [e.g. radial-gradient(...)] now confirmed to work (again?) on Microsoft Edge 17.17134. I don't know when this was added. Still not working on latest Firefox & Chrome / Windows 10.

Comment: But edge webkit browsers now support the new mozilla-heritage gradient spec as well as the older webkit syntax. Confusingly, they're both -webkit prefixed

Comment: That that IE10 fully supports gradient transitions.

Comment: [Great simple workaround here](https://medium.com/@dave_lunny/animating-css-gradients-using-only-css-d2fd7671e759)

Comment: Can you add a demonstration on using transitions with gradients now? I can't seem to figure it out based on your answer (and can find no other news about it). The last I heard, you can't transition between two background images, which is what gradients were.

Comment: I'd like to see some sources/code on this as well. I can't get it to work, even with updated 2017-syntax (which afaik means to just drop the prefixes)

Comment: Alex - updated syntax is significantly different at least for -webkit: e.g. In Old webkit syntax there was a single gradient property and radial/linear was an attribute - now they're separate properties.Which was how the -moz syntax worked.

Comment: Transitioning the opacity (and filter brightness/contrast) works great, especially when you have a background image that you want to fade in/out.

Answer (score 125):

One work-around is to transition the background position to give the effect that the gradient is changing:
http://sapphion.com/2011/10/css3-gradient-transition-with-background-position/

> ### CSS3 gradient transition with background-position
>
> Although you can’t directly animate gradients using the CSS transition property, it is possible to animate the background-position property to achieve a simple gradient animation:
>
> The code for this is dead simple:

```css
#DemoGradient{  
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#C7D3DC,#5B798E);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#C7D3DC,#5B798E);  
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#C7D3DC,#5B798E);  
    background: linear-gradient(#C7D3DC,#5B798E);  
  
    -webkit-transition: background 1s ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: background 1s ease-out;  
    -o-transition: background 1s ease-out;  
    transition: background 1s ease-out;  
  
    background-size:1px 200px;  
    border-radius: 10px;  
    border: 1px solid #839DB0;  
    cursor:pointer;  
    width: 150px;  
    height: 100px;  
}  
#DemoGradient:Hover{  
    background-position:100px;  
}
```

```html
<div id="DemoGradient"></div>
```

Answer (score 90):

It is now possible to animate gradients with [`@property`](https://caniuse.com/?search=%40property) in CSS:

```css
@property --myColor1 {
  syntax: '<color>';
  initial-value: magenta;
  inherits: false;
}

@property --myColor2 {
  syntax: '<color>';
  initial-value: #00ff00;
  inherits: false;
}
```

The rest is regular CSS.
Set the variables as initial gradient colors and also set the transition of those variables:

```css
div {
  /* Optional: change initial value of the variables */
  /* --myColor1: #f64; --myColor2: brown; */

  background: linear-gradient(var(--myColor1), var(--myColor2));
  transition: --myColor1 3s, --myColor2 3s;
}
```

Then, on the desired rule, set new values for the variables:

```css
div:hover {  
  --myColor1: #f00;
  --myColor2: yellow;
}
```

```css
@property --myColor1 {
  syntax: '<color>';
  initial-value: #0f0;
  inherits: false;
}

@property --myColor2 {
  syntax: '<color>';
  initial-value: rgb(40, 190, 145);
  inherits: false;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(var(--myColor1), var(--myColor2));
  transition: --myColor1 3s, --myColor2 3s;
}

div:hover {
  --myColor1: red;
  --myColor2: #E1AF2F;
}
```

```html
<div>Hover over me</div>
```

See the [full description and example here](https://web.dev/at-property/) and refer [here for `@property` specification](https://drafts.css-houdini.org/css-properties-values-api-1/#at-property-rule).
<sub>The @property rule is part of the CSS Houdini technology. For more information refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Houdini) and [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/05/houdini) and see [this video](https://youtu.be/5eBar5TI71M).</sub>

Comment: Can you change the CSS variables using Javascript? I was trying and can't get the fade effect, it immediately toggles.

Comment: @Verminous yes you can. You can see an example here: https://frazer.github.io/cssVariables/index.html and code here https://github.com/Frazer/cssVariables/blob/master/index.html

Comment: Works perfectly with `styled-components` and dynamic classNames using `clsx`!

Answer (score 36):

A solution is to use **background-position to mimic the gradient transition.**
This solution was used in Twitter Bootstrap a few months ago.

**Update**

http://codersblock.blogspot.fr/2013/12/gradient-animation-trick.html?showComment=1390287622614

Here is a quick example:

**Link state**

```
 .btn {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #50abdf, #1f78aa);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#50abdf), to(#1f78aa));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #50abdf, #1f78aa);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #50abdf, #1f78aa);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #50abdf, #1f78aa);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff50abdf', endColorstr='#ff1f78aa', GradientType=0);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: 100% 90px;
  background-position: 0 -30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
     -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
       -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
          transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

**Hover state**

```
.btn:hover {
   background-position: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: And here's a fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/Volker_E/RksTV/ The key is the property `background-size`, which you can't in IE8. http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size 
Apart from that it's a nice solution.

Answer (score 28):

For what it's worth, here's a Sass mixin:

**Usage:**

`@include gradientAnimation(red, blue, .6s);`

**Mixin:**

```css
@mixin gradientAnimation( $start, $end, $transTime ){
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient($start, $end);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    &:before {
        background-image: linear-gradient($end, $start);
        content: "";
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; left: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: -100;
        transition: opacity $transTime;
    }
    &:hover {
        &:before {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Taken from this awesome post on Medium from Dave Lunny: https://medium.com/@dave_lunny/animating-css-gradients-using-only-css-d2fd7671e759

Answer (score 27):

### **::before**, the CSS pseudo-element can easily do the trick!

```css
.element {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, blue, aqua);
  z-index: 2;
}

.element::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  inset: 0; /* same as { top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; } */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, orange);
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s linear;
}

.element:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="element"></div>
</body>
```

All you have to do is use the **::before** pseudo-element with zero **opacity**.

On **:hover**, switch **::before's opacity** to 1 and if you follow a few simple steps, you should get your transition working.

1. Set the element's background gradient using **background-image**

   Use the **::before** pseudo-element with **opacity** zero to setup your next gradient

   set **opacity** to **1** inside **:hover::before**

   make sure your **::before** has:

   - **position absolute**
   - **content: ""**
   - a **lower z-index** than the default element
   - zero **top**, **bottom**, **left**, and **right**  (or simply **inset: 0**)
   - **transition** targeting **opacity** with a time interval of your preference

And that's it! Now you should be able tweak your **transition**  with whatever **duration** / **delay** / **timing-function** you like!

Comment: If your initial background is transparent, you can set `z-index` of the "overlapping" background to `-1` so that your `fonts` won't get covered.

Comment: note that for inline elements that span multiple lines this might not give the desired effect. Eg. when trying to underline a link that wraps several lines, this will not work.

Answer (score 17):

I know that is old question but mabye someone enjoy my way of solution in pure CSS. Gradient fade from left to right.

```css
.contener{   
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background-size:cover;
  border:solid 2px black;
}
.ed {
    width: 0px;
    height: 200px;
    background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.75), rgba(255,0,0,0.75));
    position: relative;
    opacity:0;
    transition:width 20s, opacity 0.6s;
}

.contener:hover .ed{
    width: 300px;
    background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.75), rgba(255,0,0,0.75));
    position: relative;
    opacity:1;
    transition:width 0.4s, opacity 1.1s;
    transition-delay: width 2s;
    
    animation-name: gradient-fade;
    animation-duration: 1.1s;   
    -webkit-animation-name: gradient-fade; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
}




/* ANIMATION */
@-webkit-keyframes gradient-fade {
    0%   {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0), rgba(255,0,0,0));}
    2%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.01875), rgba(255,0,0,0));}
    4%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.0375), rgba(255,0,0,0.0));}
    6%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.05625), rgba(255,0,0,0.0));}
    8% {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.075), rgba(255,0,0,0));}
    10%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.09375), rgba(255,0,0,0));}
    12%   {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.1125), rgba(255,0,0,0));}
    14%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.13125), rgba(255,0,0,0));}
    16%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.15), rgba(255,0,0,0));}
    18%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.16875), rgba(255,0,0,0));}
    20% {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.1875), rgba(255,0,0,0));}
    22%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.20625), rgba(255,0,0,0.01875));}
    24%   {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.225), rgba(255,0,0,0.0375));}
    26%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.24375), rgba(255,0,0,0.05625));}
    28%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.2625), rgba(255,0,0,0.075));}
    30%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.28125), rgba(255,0,0,0.09375));}
    32% {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.3), rgba(255,0,0,0.1125));}
    34%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.31875), rgba(255,0,0,0.13125));}
    36%   {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.3375), rgba(255,0,0,0.15));}
    38%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.35625), rgba(255,0,0,0.16875));}
    40%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.375), rgba(255,0,0,0.1875));}
    42%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.39375), rgba(255,0,0,0.20625));}
    44% {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.4125), rgba(255,0,0,0.225));}
    46%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.43125),rgba(255,0,0,0.24375));}
    48%   {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.45), rgba(255,0,0,0.2625));}
    50%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.46875), rgba(255,0,0,0.28125));}
    52%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.4875), rgba(255,0,0,0.3));}
    54%   {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.50625), rgba(255,0,0,0.31875));}
    56%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.525), rgba(255,0,0,0.3375));}
    58%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.54375), rgba(255,0,0,0.35625));}
    60%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.5625), rgba(255,0,0,0.375));}
    62% {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.58125), rgba(255,0,0,0.39375));}
    64%  {background:linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,255,0.6), rgba(255,0,0,0.4125));}
    66%   {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.61875), rgba(255,0,0,0.43125));}
    68%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.6375), rgba(255,0,0,0.45));}
    70%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.65625), rgba(255,0,0,0.46875));}
    72%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.675), rgba(255,0,0,0.4875));}
    74% {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.69375), rgba(255,0,0,0.50625));}
    76%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.7125), rgba(255,0,0,0.525));}
    78%   {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.73125),,rgba(255,0,0,0.54375));}
    80%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.75), rgba(255,0,0,0.5625));}
    82%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.75), rgba(255,0,0,0.58125));}
    84%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.75),rgba(255,0,0,0.6));}
    86% {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.75), rgba(255,0,0,0.61875));}
    88%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.75), rgba(255,0,0,0.6375));}
    90%   {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.75), rgba(255,0,0,0.65625));}
    92%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.75), rgba(255,0,0,0.675));}
    94%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.75),rgba(255,0,0,0.69375));}
    96%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.75), rgba(255,0,0,0.7125));}
    98% {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.75), rgba(255,0,0,0.73125),);}
    100%  {background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,255,0.75), rgba(255,0,0,0.75));}
}
```

```html
<div class="contener" style="">
  <div class="ed"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Based on the css code in your question, I have try code as follows and it works for me (run the code snippet), and please try by yourself :

```css
#container div a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10%;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #C0357E, #EE5840);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
     
#container div a:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #6d8aa0, #343436);
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
}
    
#container div a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
#container div a span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"><div><a href="#"><span>Press Me</span></a></div></div>
```

Based on the css code in your question, I have try code as follows and it works for me, and please try by yourself :

```
    #container div a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10%;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #C0357E, #EE5840);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

#container div a:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #6d8aa0, #343436);
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
}

#container div a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
#container div a span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

Does it works for you? 
Change the color based on your need :)

Answer (score 4):

Partial workaround for gradient transition is to use inset box shadow - you can transition either the box shadow itself, or the background color - e.g. if you create inset box shadow of the same color as background and than use transition on background color, it creates illusion that plain background is changing to radial gradient

```
.button SPAN {
    padding: 10px 30px; 
    border: 1px solid ##009CC5;

    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px 1px #00a7d1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px 1px#00a7d1;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px 1px #00a7d1; 

    background-color: #00a7d1;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
    transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
}

.button SPAN:hover {
    background-color: #00c5f7; 
}
```

Comment: clever solution, inset shadow can create the gradient illusion perfectly

Answer (score 3):

You can FAKE transitions between gradients, using transitions in the opacity of a few stacked gradients, as described in a few of the answers here:

[CSS3 animation with gradients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654510/css3-animation-with-gradients).

You can also transition the position instead, as described here:

[CSS3 gradient transition with background-position](http://sapphion.com/2011/10/css3-gradient-transition-with-background-position/).

Some more techniques here:

[Animating CSS3 Gradients](http://www.impressivewebs.com/animating-css3-gradients/).

Answer (score 3):

In the following, an anchor tag has a child and a grandchild. The grandchild has the far background gradient. The child in the near background is transparent, but has the gradient to transition to. On hover, the child's opacity is transitioned from 0 to 1, over a period of 1 second.

Here is the CSS:

```
.bkgrndfar {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:-2;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:linear-gradient(#eee, #aaa);
}

.bkgrndnear {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:radial-gradient(at 50% 50%, blue 1%, aqua 100%);
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

a.menulnk {
  position:relative;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#333;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:27px;
  float:left;
}

a.menulnk:hover {
  color:#eee;
  text-decoration:underline;
}

/* This transitions child opacity on parent hover */
a.menulnk:hover .bkgrndnear {
  opacity:1;
}
```

And, this is the HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="menulnk">Transgradient
<div class="bkgrndfar">
  <div class="bkgrndnear">
  </div>
</div>
</a>
```

The above is only tested in the latest version of Chrome. These are the before hover, halfway on-hover and fully transitioned on-hover images:

[image: Before] [image: Halfway] [image: After]

Answer (score 3):

Found a nice hack on codepen that modifies the `opacity` property but achieves that fade from one gradient to another by leveraging pseudo-elements. What he does is he sets an `:after` so that when you change the opacity of the actual element, the `:after` element shows up so it looks as if it were a fade. Thought it'd be useful to share.

Original codepen: http://codepen.io/sashtown/pen/DfdHh

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10%;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #6d8aa0, #8ba2b4);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
.button:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ca5f5e, #d68584);
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
}
.button:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.button span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#"><span>BUTTON</span></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to have a div appear like a 3D sphere and transition through colors.
I discovered that gradient background colors don't transition (yet).
I placed a radial gradient background in front of the element (using z-index) with a transitioning solid background.

```
/* overlay */
z-index : 1;
background : radial-gradient( ellipse at 25% 25%, rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0 ) 0%, rgba( 0, 0, 0, 1 ) 100% );
```

then the `div.ball` underneath:

```
transition : all 1s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
```

then changed the background color of the `div.ball` and voila!

https://codepen.io/keldon/pen/dzPxZP

Answer (score 2):

As stated. Gradients aren't currently supported with CSS Transitions. But you could work around it in some cases by setting one of the colors to transparent, so that the background-color of some other wrapping element shines through, and transition that instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try use :before and :after (ie9+)

```
#wrapper{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
    position:relative;}
#wrapper:after,
#wrapper:before{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    content:'';
    background: #1e5799;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(50%,#2989d8), color-stop(51%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%);
    opacity:1;
    z-index:-1;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease-out;
    transition: all 2s ease-out;
}
#wrapper:after{
    opacity:0;
    background: #87e0fd;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #87e0fd 0%, #53cbf1 40%, #05abe0 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#87e0fd), color-stop(40%,#53cbf1), color-stop(100%,#05abe0));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%);
}
#wrapper:hover:before{opacity:0;}
#wrapper:hover:after{opacity:1;}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this at work :) IE6+
https://gist.github.com/GrzegorzPerko/7183390

Don't forget about `<element class="ahover"><span>Text</span></a>` if you use a text element.

```
.ahover {
    display: block;
    /** text-indent: -999em; ** if u use only only img **/
    position: relative;
}
.ahover:after {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.ahover:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
.ahover span {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't hurt to post another view since there's still not an official way to do this. Wrote a lightweight jQuery plugin with which you can define a background radial gradient and a transition speed. This basic usage will then let it fade in, optimised with requestAnimationFrame (very smooth) :

```
$('#element').gradientFade({

    duration: 2000,
    from: '(20,20,20,1)',
    to: '(120,120,120,0)'
});
```

http://codepen.io/Shikkediel/pen/xbRaZz?editors=001

Keeps original background and all properties intact. Also has highlight tracking as a setting :

http://codepen.io/Shikkediel/pen/VYRZZY?editors=001

Answer (score 1):

A much cleaner solution would be to set the background color and use a mask-image.

```
#container div a {
  background-color: blue;
  transition: background 0.2s linear;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  mask-image: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .7), rgba(0, 0, 0, .4));
}

#container div a:hover { 
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to 2023 on a super old post. But, I landed here and obviously you did also.

CSS Only

https://jsfiddle.net/BradChesney79/rpa8v50t/

Markup:

```
<div class="fx-button">
<div class="button-content">
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAhCAYAAAALboFLAAABhGlDQ1BJQ0MgcHJvZmlsZQAAKJF9kT1Iw0AcxV+/UKTFwQ4iHTJUB7EgKuKoVShChVArtOpgcukXNGlIUlwcBdeCgx+LVQcXZ10dXAVB8APE1cVJ0UVK/F9SaBHjwXE/3t173L0D/M0qU83gOKBqlpFJJYVcflXoeUUQIUQQw6jETH1OFNPwHF/38PH1LsGzvM/9OSJKwWSATyCeZbphEW8QT29aOud94igrSwrxOfGYQRckfuS67PIb55LDfp4ZNbKZeeIosVDqYrmLWdlQiaeI44qqUb4/57LCeYuzWq2z9j35C8MFbWWZ6zRjSGERSxAhQEYdFVRhIUGrRoqJDO0nPfxDjl8kl0yuChg5FlCDCsnxg//B727N4uSEmxROAqEX2/4YBnp2gVbDtr+Pbbt1AgSegSut4681gZlP0hsdLX4E9G8DF9cdTd4DLneAwSddMiRHCtD0F4vA+xl9Ux4YuAX61tze2vs4fQCy1FX6Bjg4BEZKlL3u8e7e7t7+PdPu7wdXSnKcEOSXsgAAAAZiS0dEAKMAmwCI3OECOgAAAAlwSFlzAAAuIwAALiMBeKU/dgAAAAd0SU1FB+cEBQ8XBXt+4EwAAAAZdEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVBXgQ4XAAABn0lEQVQ4y02UQZJjIQxDn4Rz/7nCrOeEqQlWLww/vUlR+WDZTwL9+/snpAlBLAAs0QkSSKJs0b1YBCQiIUQZEgCoz/9NAh/CfIZtkTQILFPLphMiIALNRmKYFdU92sHPhiBkgRphyssALDFi0qkCWEimktCnQRlo5keCT4BN7b2JjBLSAhnRTz9I1FqLzowvmWQmCsMIgUnONMxpQZLZMH9SO5m1IOlv80cKRJGQDF0pY8eZjEu872hA0wP0yM9K1OtVdPdBsAhgBq41ttfuTXI49zTXBPnyC2V8FExuE4H0o0eNWZk83al4NKenz2c/p/FUUyYRQoQMzLsnV+qBO4rVCeked3tgXjsu+fJa57iQ/SQ9OpkCisMoYioC+1pzBql61bEl4DWkEyLBlXu/3xy3CB/SYOtJBECtVd/G7amkb/MEqrtJQnqPDDrs9QtB91euQ3efe3Dpi3oSmCm/amEy8nruXU8FgWRI0z4X9PZki9Z9KuYt8C+fsSgQT+btyXjOvUtIQslC+aYWglYNSHtg9t6TwA6Rz0vQ493J2g8fnASMeeRW2QAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
<span class="button-text">DESKTOP BUTTON WITH COLOR SHIFT</span>
</div>
</div>
<p>
Drop shadow intrudes into immediate space around the element.
</p>
<p>
Not a particular issue, but something to be aware of.
</p>
```

CSS:

```
p {
   border: 1px red solid;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;"
}


.fx-button {
  background-image: linear-gradient(15deg, #a09486, #d2c7af);
  border: 1px red solid;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 13px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 13px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  color: white;
  height: 33px;
  margin: 0;
  paddng: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: fit-content;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fx-button::before {
  background-image: linear-gradient(15deg, #d2c7af, #a09486);
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
  z-index: -1;
}
.fx-button:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.button-text {
  border: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px 0 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: -11px;
}
.button-content {
  border: 0;
  height: 33px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: fit-content;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Very much

```css
.element {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, blue, aqua);
  z-index: 2;
}

.element::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  inset: 0; /* same as { top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; } */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, orange);
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s linear;
}

.element:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="element"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you clarify how this solves the question being asked?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and simple method using `background-blend-mode`

```css
.grad {
  height: 100px;
  width: 180px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 8px;
  
  /* gradient styling */
  transition: 0.5s background-color;
  background-color: #888; /* initial luminosity */
  background-image: linear-gradient(DodgerBlue, MediumSlateBlue);
  background-blend-mode: color;
}
.grad:hover {
  background-color: #aaa; /* hover state luminosity */
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grad"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

It only transitions between two luminosity values, so use it in cases where a simple effect is sufficient. It's a CSS only solution and doesn't require preparing an image. (Although it can of course be used with an image too.)

[More on the background-blend-mode property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode)

[Reference of blend mode types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/blend-mode)