# Animating a CSS gradient background on the hover event

Tags: html, css

I have some menu items that are styled using a background gradient on hover using the following styling:

```css
#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(68,68,68) 5%, rgb(51,51,51) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(68,68,68) 5%, rgb(51,51,51) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(68,68,68) 5%, rgb(51,51,51) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(68,68,68) 5%, rgb(51,51,51) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(68,68,68) 5%, rgb(51,51,51) 100%);

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0.05, rgb(68,68,68)),
        color-stop(1, rgb(51,51,51))
    );
    color: #f0f0f0;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
```

My question is, is it possible to make the new background (defined by gradients) slide in from the right using CSS3 transitions or animations? Or will I have to resort to using a sprite image or Javascript?

Comment: A little late but for future reference - here's a jQuery solution that does an actual fade using the animate progress function : http://stackoverflow.com/a/27790093/3168107

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Animation on gradients aren't supported yet. However this site provides a pleasing approach for a animated kind of feel on hover-

http://sapphion.com/2011/10/css3-gradient-transition-with-background-position/

Sample css:-

```
#DemoGradient{  
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#C7D3DC,#5B798E);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#C7D3DC,#5B798E);  
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#C7D3DC,#5B798E);  
    background: linear-gradient(#C7D3DC,#5B798E);  

    -webkit-transition: background 1s ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: background 1s ease-out;  
    -o-transition: background 1s ease-out;  
    transition: background 1s ease-out;  

    background-size:1px 200px;  
    border-radius: 10px;  
    border: 1px solid #839DB0;  
    cursor:pointer;  
    width: 150px;  
    height: 100px;  
}  
#DemoGradient:Hover{  
    background-position:100px;  
}
```

Comment: seriously gradients are STILL not animatable? it's been on the cards for at least 3 years now...

Comment: Thanks! so it's just the background-position that you have to animate;]

Answer (score 1):

It seems gradients don't support transitions yet (still):

[Use CSS3 transitions with gradient backgrounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542212/use-css3-transitions-with-gradient-backgrounds)

If you use a background image rather than a css3 gradient, then you can use css transition to animate it in and out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as a hack:

```
<div class="background-animate">
  <div class="content">Hi im content</div>
</div>
```

And style it

```
.background-animate {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;
    background: transparent;
}
.background-animate:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    transition: opacity .35s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .35s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .35s ease-in-out;
    top:0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; z-index:-1;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 40%, #e9eae9 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 40%,#e9eae9 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #ffffff 40%,#e9eae9 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
}
.background-animate:hover:before {
    opacity: 0;
}
.background-animate:after {
    content: ""; opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .35s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .35s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .35s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    top:0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; z-index:-1;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 80%, #e9eae9 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 80%,#e9eae9 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #ffffff 80%,#e9eae9 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
}
.background-animate:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

It basically does an opacity switch between to gradients. Demo found here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eWOEoR

Comment: Its 2023 and gradient transitions are not supported haha.
Just setting up `:before & :after then with hovers` changing opacity is still the easiest way changing between gradial gradient colors that has transition. Just dont forget to add `z-index` to `:after`