# Rotate gradient

Tags: css, gradient

I'm using the following code from [Animating a CSS gradient background on the hover event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116689/animating-a-css-gradient-background-on-the-hover-event) which is amazing.  However, I'd like the gradient to be left to right.

```
.gradient {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(lightgray,white);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(lightgray,white);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(lightgray,white);
    background: linear-gradient(lightgray,white);
    -webkit-transition: background 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: background 1s ease-out;
    transition: background 1s ease-out;
    -moz-background-size: 1px 200px;
    -o-background-size: 1px 200px;
    -webkit-background-size: 1px 200px;
    background-size: 1px 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.gradient:Hover {
    background-position: 100px;
}
```

I tried adding left and replacing background with background-image as discussed here: http://www.webdirections.org/blog/css3-linear-gradients/

```
.gradient {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, lightgray,white);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, lightgray,white);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, lightgray,white);
    background: linear-gradient(left, lightgray,white);
    -webkit-transition: background 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: background 1s ease-out;
    transition: background 1s ease-out;
    -moz-background-size: 1px 200px;
    -o-background-size: 1px 200px;
    -webkit-background-size: 1px 200px;
    background-size: 1px 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.gradient:Hover {
    background-position: 100px;
}
```

Still no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the background size, if I understand ok what you are trying has the wrong dimensions

```
.gradient {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, lightgray,white);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, lightgray,white);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, lightgray,white);
    background: linear-gradient(left, lightgray,white);
    -webkit-transition: background 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: background 1s ease-out;
    transition: background 1s ease-out;
    -moz-background-size: 200px 1px;
    -o-background-size: 200px 1px;
    -webkit-background-size: 200px 1px;
    background-size: 200px 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/hjMq6/1/)

Just thinking about it, the dimensions are predefined, so your class is not reusable. You can make it resolution independent, and the way it works is more easily understood. Just change the background sixe to

```
    background-size: 200% 100%;
```

well, the y dimension is not relevant, but setting it to 100% is clearer.
and the hover to

```
.gradient:hover {
    background-position: 100%;
}
```

## [updated demo with 2 sizes](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/hjMq6/2/)

Comment: Nice that it helped you. I have added a better solution.