# CSS background (gradient) transition not working

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions, transition

The CSS transition on my a tag isn't fading in and out, its just like there's no transition at all! I tried using `transition: background 300ms ease-in-out;` too but still no luck

CSS:

```
.FeatureRow a{
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 260px;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px #f5f5f5;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px #f5f5f5;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px #f5f5f5;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fbfbfb,#ffffff);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#fbfbfb),to(#ffffff));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fbfbfb,#ffffff);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fbfbfb,#ffffff);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fbfbfb,#ffffff);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
.FeatureRow a:hover{
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#C00,#C0F);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#C00),to(#C0F));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#C00,#C0F);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#C00,#C0F);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#C00,#C0F);
}
```

Answer (score 15):

As Adrift says, this is not supported; you have to simulate it.

This is the CSS

```
.FeatureRow {
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 260px;
    height: 70px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg,white,gray);
}

.FeatureRow:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg,red,magenta);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
}

.FeatureRow:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

We are overlaying your div with a pseudo element. Each one has a gradient. The pseudo element has opacity set to 0; when you hover it you change the opacity to 1; and this property can be transitioned.

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xA4qa/)

Comment: This does not work for buttons unfortunately

Comment: appreciate it man this worked for me!

Comment: @SethB it does work, if the problem you are having is the text being hidden behind a background, make sure you put **z-index: 1** on your btn, and **z-index: -1** on your :after

Answer (score 8):

As noted in other answers, it is not possible to animate a gradient. It is however possible to animate **background-color**. Knowing this, you can layer a transparent gradient on top of a background color, which will allow you to animate one of the colors in your gradient.

To do this, choose the color you want to animate, set it as the **background-color**, and put **`rgba(0,0,0,0)`** (transparent) in its place.

Then all you have to do is on **:hover or with javascript** change  **background-color** to your desired value

> This will only work to transition **one color** of your gradient. But I think it's still a decent option to transition a gradient

```css
.squareTile {
 background: radial-gradient(#203244eb, rgba(0,0,0,0), #203244eb);
 background-color: #3596ff;
 border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: 1s;
}

.squareTile:hover {
 background-color: #77c577;
}
```

```html
<div class="squareTile">
</div>
```

Comment: This is actually quite a clever answer. It won't work in very situation of course, but way to think outside the box!

Answer (score 4):

Using gradients for animations (or transitions) is unfortunately not [supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116689/animating-a-css-gradient-background-on-the-hover-event) by any browser at the moment. Take a look at [this list](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-css) in the [Transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/) module for a list of all current animatible properties

Comment: Is it possible to use a background image and then use a transition to "overwrite" the image with just background-color?

Comment: You unfortunately can't do that either because background-images aren't animatible. Take a look at the list in my answer.

Comment: Great.. this proves that all these new CSS3 tricks are becoming as complex as useless.

Answer (score 0):

animating a background gradient is possible, as mentioned, and there's a quite good tool currently up to let you play with the feature:

https://www.gradient-animator.com/

example output:

```
.css-selector {
    background: linear-gradient(270deg, #8ccebd, #146e57);
    background-size: 400% 400%;

    animation: AnimationName 5s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
```