# CSS Transition not firing when adding class to body (Firefox)

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox

I am creating a sticky header on a site that decreases padding of 2 elements once the page starts scrolling.  To do so, I add a class to the body tag once scrolling begins and have transitions set up to animate once that class is added.  This works fine in webkit browsers but not in firefox?  Here is a JSFiddle of the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/5HLyu/11/. Any help is appreciated!

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        Header
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        Menu
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body{height:1000px; overflow:scroll; padding:0; margin:0}
.header{background:#00457c; color:#fff; padding:22px 0; text-align:center;
    -webkit-transition:all 250ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition:all 250ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition:all 250ms ease-out;
    -o-transition:all 250ms ease-out;
    transition:all 250ms ease-out;
}
.menu{background:#aaa; padding:22px 0; text-align:center;
    -webkit-transition:all 250ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition:all 250ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition:all 250ms ease-out;
    -o-transition:all 250ms ease-out;
    transition:all 250ms ease-out;
}

.down .header-wrapper{position:fixed; top:0; width:100%; z-index:1000}
.down .header{padding:10px 0}
.down .menu{padding:10px 0}
```

jQuery

```
(function($){
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        $("body").toggleClass("down", (fromTop > 1));
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I am unable to replicate this issue in firefox, or anyother brower i know of, are you running the latest version?

Comment: Yes. Running version 30.0 on OSX 10.9.3

Comment: You could try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499422/css-transition-only-working-in-firefox?rq=1

Comment: Not sure is this page is a duplicate or not

Comment: I don't think that thread is similar to this issue. That is trying to animate a pseudo element of an image. This is an issue related to elements not animating in firefox when a class is added

Comment: its not exactly the same question, but the answer is basicaly the same, you will have to find a work-around if the problem persists, as there is nothing "wrong" with your code.

Comment: I don't know one off the top of my head, but I am sure there is a JS solution to creating the same transaction which should be compatible cross browser.  If you can wait, then an update will probably be released in the near future giving more compatibility.

Comment: sadly I may have to go the JS route if I can't find an alternative or a fix as this project has a deadline of june 30th. thanks for your help though!

Comment: No problem.  Just messing around with your code, I found that the animation works smoother if you change from (250ms ease-out;)
to a higher value(for example 1000ms) in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FF seems to have issues with transitions if you change an elements `position`

Change this line:

`.down .header-wrapper{position:fixed; top:0; width:100%; z-index:1000}`

To this:

`.header-wrapper{position:fixed; top:0; width:100%; z-index:1000}`

(ie. remove the `.down` selector)

I don't believe this will have any negative effect on your code.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5HLyu/15/)

Comment: that worked! only thing i had to do was adjust the margin of the next element on the site so that it accounted for the header being outside the document flow. thanks!

Comment: Cool. You could probably have also added some padding to your `body`