# webkit transition not working

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions

http://jsfiddle.net/cJrgB/

The hyperlinks in `#shortcut-bar` are given `-webkit-transition: background .25s ease-in-out`. But it doesn't work. I also tried with `all .25s ease-in-out`

The lines of code corresponding to my problem are under:

`/* vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv here vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv */`

PS: Please explain to me what `ease-in-out` `ease-in` `ease-out` `ease` etc mean

PS2: Also, which place is beter for transition property, in `:hover` pseudo-class or in its general area, the one without `:hover`

Comment: You can't use the `transition` property to animate [gradients as of now :(](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542212/use-css3-transitions-with-gradient-backgrounds)

Answer (score 0):

Ad main question: I think transition doesn't work with gradients.

Ad PS: see [CSS3 Transitions](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/)

Ad PSS: if you add trasition to `:hover` it will only be active on `:hover`, so when you 'unhover', there will be no transition at all.