# How can I animate my text to highlight from left to right?

Tags: css, css-animations

I've been looking for a way to make this work and I can't quite find what I want at this point.

I have this text that I want to highlight, and I would like to animate that to go from left to right. As of now, I've managed to make the highlight appear after a set amount of time, but without the left-to-right effect.

Here's what it looks like right now for reference :

[image]

And this is the css I used to make this happen :

```
@keyframes highlight {
    0% {
        background: none;
    }

    100% {
        background: linear-gradient(to top, $light-purple 50%, transparent 50%);
    }
}

h2 {
    display: inline;
    animation-name: highlight;
    animation-duration: 0.75s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

I know this is a very rookie question, but I honestly can't find a way to do it properly, considering what I already have... I would appreciate it if someone could help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide a working example please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animating Linear Gradient using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23441060/animating-linear-gradient-using-css)

Comment: If possible, I would recommend adding enough code to constitute a [mcve], preferably as a runnable snippet, along with steps to reproduce the issue.  This will go a long way in enabling the community to provide you with helpful direction.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution inspired by [this article](https://wesbos.com/css-highlight-animation) :

```css
@keyframes highlight {
    from {
      background-position: 0;
    }

    to {
      background-position: -100%;
    }
}

h2 {
    animation-name: highlight;
    animation-duration: 0.75s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    background-size: 200%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white 50%, transparent 50%), 
                      linear-gradient(transparent 50%, purple 50%);
}
```

```html
<h2>Here is an example text that will have the highlight</h2>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works wonders. My only problem is that I would love to keep the highlight like at 50% of the text height, just like in the picture I put. Which, with your solution, is impossible for me since I use linear-gradient to top to do that. Any ideas how I could still achieve that ? Thanks!

Comment: @almecin I think you could set a white color that hides the highlight color like `background-image: linear-gradient(to left, white 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(transparent 50%, red 100%);` and then this animation would slide the white color and reveal the highlight color. This would require you to set the background initial color according to where the text is.

Comment: I updated my answer using the code of @aerial301

Comment: @aerial301 Thanks to the both of you!!