# How to add transition animation to gradient text background when hovered?

Tags: html, css

How do I add an animation from plain color to background gradient color when hovered? Possibly when hovered from left to right?

I have this sample code but when hovered it is too instant when changing the colors.

I've tried using these references:

[Use CSS3 transitions with gradient backgrounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542212/use-css3-transitions-with-gradient-backgrounds)

[Animating Linear Gradient using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23441060/animating-linear-gradient-using-css)

But can't seem to figure out how to have an easiest approach for the hover. Other references say to add pseudo after element when hovered, but it seems a bit complicated when using it. Just want to use the hover element when animating the gradient text to it.

How to add a transition with these types of gradient text colors?

**SAMPLE CODE:**

```css
.hover-grad-txt {
  font-size:100px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#191335;
  background-image:linear-gradient(to right, #191335, #191335);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hover-grad-txt:hover {
  background-image:linear-gradient(to right, #01A5F8, #01BFD8);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<span class="hover-grad-txt">Spear</span>
```

Comment: Could you explain what 'possibly hovered from left to right' would mean? Is the linear-gradient to move as the user moves the mouse from left to right over the element?

Comment: for your reference, the answer you accepted exists in the duplicate and not only one time but many times

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To animate it, instead of trying to animate the gradient, you could animate it's position.

**Let's use a new linear gradient for you background.**
It will go from the solid color, then it will be a gradient to your
first color from the gradient, then it will be a gradient to the second color of your gradient.

Something like this:
`background-image:linear-gradient(to right, #191335, #191335 33.33333%, #01A5F8 66.66666%, #01BFD8);`

Then you adapt the size to only see the solid color:
`background-size: 300% 100%;`

And it's position:
`background-position: top left;`

All you need to do on hover is to move it:
`background-position: top left 100%;`

```css
.hover-grad-txt {
  font-size:100px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#191335;
  background-image:linear-gradient(to right, #191335, #191335 33.33333%, #01A5F8 66.66666%, #01BFD8);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-size: 300% 100%;
  background-position: top left;
  transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.hover-grad-txt:hover {
  background-position: top left 100%;
}
```

```html
<span class="hover-grad-txt">Spear</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using new CSS properties, you could also do it like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @property --a {
                syntax: '<color>';
                inherits: false;
                initial-value: #191335;
            }

            @property --b {
                syntax: '<color>';
                inherits: false;
                initial-value: #191335;
            }

            .hover-grad-txt {
                transition: --a 0.5s, --b 0.5s;
                font-size: 100px;
                text-align: center;
                background-image: linear-gradient(to right, var(--a), var(--b));
                -webkit-background-clip: text;
                -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
            }

            .hover-grad-txt:hover {
                --a:#01A5F8;
                --b: #01BFD8;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="hover-grad-txt">Spear</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind it only works in Chrome. Also, look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23441060/animating-linear-gradient-using-css).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to these answer, you could also utilize `@keyframes` to specify the animation code. Example here is setting `pretty` as the `@keyframe` and placing `rgba` value with `Alpha` set to 0 to ensure hovering occurs still. I place crimson color as to see the changes more obvios.

```css
.hover-grad-txt {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, crimson, #01A5F8, #01BFD8);
  background-size: 200% 200%;
  animation: pretty 2s ease-in-out infinite;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.hover-grad-txt:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

@keyframes pretty {
  0% {
    background-position: left
  }
  50% {
    background-position: right
  }
  100% {
    background-position: left
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hover-grad-txt">Spear</div>
```