# why don't my backgraund gradients work in my css code

Tags: css, gradient

This is my code, gradient does not run in my css code

```
body{
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #153b6a,#1a5981,#31829d,#8abac8,#c5e9e8 );
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    animation: gradient 10s linear infinite;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkJNc.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Animate Gradients using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23441060/how-to-animate-gradients-using-css)

Comment: Any success with my answer? :D

Answer (score 0):

You want the background to be larger than the base canvas, and to allow the position to be animated. I've also added keyframes

Try this

```
body{
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #153b6a, #1a5981, #31829d, #8abac8, #c5e9e8);
background-size: 200% 200%;
animation: gradient 10s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes gradient {
0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
}
50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
}
100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
}
```

}