# How change css using variables to make an animation

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, setinterval, gradient

How can I transition CSS values using JavaScript?
I made this code, but it isn't working:

```
var num = 100;
function fillDiv{
var a=document.getElementById("principal");
for (var i = 0; i<100; i++){
    num=num-25;
    a.style.background="-moz-radial-gradient(#FFFFFF "+num+"%, #006699 200%);";
    if (num==0){
       break;
    }
 }
```

In the debug window all gone good, but when I check it on elements tag the value hasn't changed.

Comment: The browser has no time to redraw each time you change the value. Use CSS transitions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542212/use-css3-transitions-with-gradient-backgrounds.

Comment: you are doing the animation in milliseconds, you wont even see them

Comment: @CodeiSir I think you mean sub-microseconds, but it wouldn't matter any way, since the browser will not redraw in the midst of running JS.

Comment: @torazaburo, sometimes it does redraw, but only if it takes very long

Comment: @torazaburo thanks mate, very interesting reference, but those are unknown friends to me, maybe can I use the .setTimeout to made the animation?

Comment: @Jnewbie, use `setInterval()`, check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in comments, the `for` loop is too quick to notice the effect, Instead you may use `interval`, set the interval period to `40` this is like `25` frames per second, also made the step `10` instead of `4` in `num = num - 10;` so that the animation will look smooth and noticeable like below:

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/t1oe619a/2/)

```js
var num = 100;

var $interval = setInterval(function() {
  var a = document.getElementById("principal");
  num = num - 10;
  if (num >= 0) {
    a.style.background = '-moz-radial-gradient(#FFF ' + num + '%,#1e69de 200%)';
    a.style.background = '-webkit-radial-gradient(#FFF ' + num + '%,#1e69de 200%)';
    a.style.background = 'radial-gradient(#FFF ' + num + '%,#1e69de 200%)';
  } else {
    clearInterval($interval);
  }
}, 40);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#principal {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  background-color: #1e69de;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="principal"></div>
```

Comment: Well done mate, thats what i was thinking about to fix it, very accurate to avoid transitions ( the only thing that make me mad its that my classmate got the same code i posted and it works for him!!) sorry for my bad english

Comment: You welcome, you need to kick the heck out of your classmate for this:) just kidding, In "*pure*" javascript I couldn't think of another way to do it, well actually I did think of getting rid of the Interval and make use of the `setTimeout()` as a "*DELAY*" function but it didn't work for me, I think if it was jQuery I could make use of the `.delay()` function, but as raw javascript nothing other than this solution in the answer worked for me