# Make gradient background button with hover effect in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

Although it seems like a basic question i wasn't able to find the solution to this problem. What I want is a gradient background button like this(https://prnt.sc/r0mx54). When the user hovers over this button then I want this behavior (https://prnt.sc/r0mxtj). Now the problem is I can make this effect by changing the background color from gradient to any normal color(in this case white). But when I try to achieve this effect by setting the background to either transparent or inherit then I wasn't able to do so.  Here is my code. Please help. 
Normal button feature gradient background-color. Hover button feature gradient border, transparent background-color.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.border-radius-20 {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.color-white {
  color: #fff;
}

.all-center {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bg-gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #049eca, #12adb8, #1cb8aa 70%);
}

li {
  padding: 2px;
}

li:hover a {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="flex relative all-center border-radius-20 bg-gradient">
    <a href="#" class="pd-8-10 border-radius-20 bg-gradient color-white uppercase">Schedule a Meeting</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can u plz send html code?

Comment: @Manikandan2811 sorry. I edited my question. It is a typo error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS - smooth button gradient color transition on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37909841/css-smooth-button-gradient-color-transition-on-hover)

Comment: Do u want to switch the background gradient color on hover?

Comment: @Manikandan2811 yes. But I want a gradient border too. Background changes to transparent while button have a gradient border.

Comment: @Pranay kumar ok.. In normal mode button have a gradient bg.. On hover, transparent bg, and gradient border. color of text?

Comment: @Manikandan2811 in normal mode button has a gradient-bg. On hover, transparent bg, gradient border, and color of the text is anything as we can easily change the color as per our requirement.

Comment: related to get some idea about how to handle transparency: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51496341/8620333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea using `mask` based on this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51496341/8620333):

```css
.button {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
  padding:5px;
  font-size:25px;
  width:250px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:1.8;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,red,blue) 0 0/0 0;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:50px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  transition:1s all;
}
.button:before,
.button:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-image:inherit;
  border-radius:inherit;
  transition:1s all;
}
.button:before {
  -webkit-mask:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) top   /100% 5px no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) bottom/100% 5px no-repeat,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at left,transparent calc(100% - 6px), #fff calc(100% - 5px)) right/27px 100% no-repeat,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at right,transparent calc(100% - 6px), #fff calc(100% - 5px)) left/27px 100% no-repeat;
  mask:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) top   /100% 5px no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) bottom/100% 5px no-repeat,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at left,transparent calc(100% - 6px), #fff calc(100% - 5px)) right/27px 100% no-repeat,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at right,transparent calc(100% - 6px), #fff calc(100% - 5px)) left/27px 100% no-repeat;
}

.button:hover::after {
  opacity:0;
}
.button:hover {
  color:red;
}

body {
  background:linear-gradient(to right,gray,white)
}
```

```html
<div class="button"> some text</div>
```

The same trick using an SVG:

```css
.button {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
  padding:5px;
  font-size:25px;
  width:250px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:1.8;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,red,blue) 0 0/0 0;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:50px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  transition:1s all;
}
.button:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-image:inherit;
  border-radius:inherit;
  transition:1s all;
}

.button:hover::after {
  opacity:0;
}
.button:hover {
  color:red;
}

.hide {
 height:0;
 width:0;
}
.button svg {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  z-index:-1;
}

body {
  background:linear-gradient(to right,gray,white)
}
```

```html
<svg class="hide" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs><linearGradient id="Gradient" x1="0" x2="250" y1="0" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><stop stop-color="red" offset="0"/><stop stop-color="blue" offset="1"/></linearGradient></defs><rect x="3" y="3" width="100%" height="100%" id="border" style="height:calc(100% - 6px);width:calc(100% - 6px)" rx="25" ry="25" stroke-width="5" fill="transparent" stroke="url(#Gradient)"/></svg>

<div class="button">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <use href="#border" />
</svg>
some text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this simple method

```
<input type="button" class="button" value="Schedule a meeting"/>

.button {
    background-color: #059fc9;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #059fc9, #1cb8aa);
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #1cb8aa;
    border: 2px solid #1cb8aa;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `.bg-gradient` to only parent element and on hover make **background** as **transparent** and apply border, See the example below.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.border-radius-20 {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.color-white {
  color: #fff;
}

.all-center {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bg-gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #049eca, #12adb8, #1cb8aa 70%);
}

.bg-gradient:hover {
 background: transparent;
 border: 1px solid #1cb8aa;
}

li {
  padding: 2px;
}

li:hover a {
  color: #1cb8aa;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="flex relative all-center border-radius-20 bg-gradient">
    <a href="#" class="pd-8-10 border-radius-20 color-white uppercase">Schedule a Meeting</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I added bg-gradient to child element as I wanted gradient border on hover.

Answer (score 0):

Source for gradient border - https://css-tricks.com/gradient-borders-in-css/

Added :hover to change the background for the inside div.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background: #222;
}

.module-border-wrap {
  max-width: 250px;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, purple);
  padding: 3px;
}
.module-border-wrap:hover .module {
  background: #222;
}
.module {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, purple);
  color: white;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
   

   <div class="module-border-wrap">
<div class="module">
    Lorem ipsum
</div>
   </div>
```

Comment: when I try to change the code for a transparent background(module-border-wrap hover effect which change the background color of the module to #222), it doesn't work. Transparent background, this is the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
.flex{
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.border-radius-20{
border-radius:20px;
}
.uppercase{
text-transform:uppercase;
}
.color-white{
color:#fff;
}
.all-center{
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}

li{
padding:2px;
position: relative;
border-radius:20px;
transition: all .3s ease;
cursor:pointer;
}
li a {
transition: all .3s ease;
text-decoration: none;
}
.bg-gradient:before{
content:'';
position: absolute;
display: block;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(to right,#049eca,#12adb8,#1cb8aa 70%);
border-radius:20px;
z-index: -1;
transition: all .3s ease;
}
.bg-gradient:after{
content:'';
position: absolute;
display: block;
opacity:0;
top:2px;
left:2px;
width: calc(100% - 4px);
height: calc(100% - 4px);
background: white;
border-radius:20px;
z-index: -1;
transition: all .3s ease;
}
.bg-gradient:hover:after {
opacity: 1;
}
li:hover a {
color: #1cb8aa;
}
```

```html
<li class="flex relative all-center bg-gradient">
<a href="#" class="pd-8-10 border-radius-20 color-white uppercase">Schedule a Meeting</a></li>
```

Comment: @Yousef thanks but I want a border with gradient too.

Comment: Thanks @Yousef, it nearly solves the problem but on hover, I want transparent background along with gradient border.