# css change color smoothly with js

Tags: javascript, css, colors, transition

I have a js code which changes a css color, but my problem is, that i wan't to change the color smoothly.

HTML:

```
<html id="html">
```

Here is the css:

```
html{
    background:radial-gradient(circle, #ffffff, #aaaaaa);
    transition:all 5s linear;
}
```

And thats the simple js:

```
function changecolor(r,g,b){
    var bg = document.getElementById("html");
    bg.style.backgroundImage = 'radial-gradient(circle, #ffffff, #'+r+g+b+ ')';
};
```

And then somewhere in the code:

```
changecolor(9,0,0);
```

The color changes perfectly but the transition isn't working. Like I said before I want the color to change smoothly.

Can anyone help me please? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use CSS3 transitions with gradient backgrounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542212/use-css3-transitions-with-gradient-backgrounds)

Answer (score 1):

I believe using javascript to set the CSS means the `transition` is bypassed. I'd recommend using javascript to set the `class` and then use CSS to manage the styling:

```
function changecolor(r,g,b){
    var bg = document.getElementById("html");
    bg.className = "alt-bg";
};
```

CSS:

```
.alt-bg {
  background-image: styles-here;
}
```

Note: this does not take into account your setting the colors through variables, it's dependent upon your specific needs whether this will work for you. IMO it's better to add/remove classes and figure out a way to make the colours variable elsewhere if at all possible.