# Use CSS3 transitions with gradient backgrounds with before and after pseudo elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This question is similar to [Use CSS3 transitions with gradient backgrounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542212/use-css3-transitions-with-gradient-backgrounds) however there is one big difference which renders the answers  unusable on the linked question for this example.

---

In the following code example, I have a menu button which has a background consisting of a linear gradient. When this button is clicked on the middle line should fade away; however, instead of fading away, it instantly disappears. This is not the effect I was after. You can see it below or in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fzL8pLb6/2/)

```js
var toggleOpenClose = 0;
var menuButton = $("#bt-menu");

menuButton.click(function() {
  if(toggleOpenClose % 2 == 0) {
    menuButton.removeClass('bt-menu-close').addClass('bt-menu-open');
    menuButton.children(".bt-menu-trigger").children("span").removeClass("close").addClass("open");
  } else {
    menuButton.removeClass('bt-menu-open').addClass('bt-menu-close');
    menuButton.children(".bt-menu-trigger").children("span").removeClass("open").addClass("close");
  }

  toggleOpenClose++;
});

var time = 1;
var timeShortSlide = 0.8;

document.styleSheets[0].addRule(".bt-menu-trigger span.open", "transition: background " + timeShortSlide + "s; transition-delay: " + (time - timeShortSlide) + "s;");
document.styleSheets[0].addRule(".bt-menu-trigger span.open:before", "transition: transform " + timeShortSlide + "s; transition-delay: " + (time - timeShortSlide) + "s;");
document.styleSheets[0].addRule(".bt-menu-trigger span.open:after", "transition: transform " + timeShortSlide + "s; transition-delay: " + (time - timeShortSlide) + "s;");
document.styleSheets[0].addRule(".bt-menu-trigger span.close", "transition: background " + timeShortSlide + "s;");
document.styleSheets[0].addRule(".bt-menu-trigger span.close:before", "transition: transform " + timeShortSlide + "s;");
document.styleSheets[0].addRule(".bt-menu-trigger span.close:after", "transition: transform " + timeShortSlide + "s;");
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bt-menu {
  width: 50px;
}
.bt-menu .bt-menu-trigger {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.bt-menu .bt-menu-trigger span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  background: #adadff;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, blue, transparent);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, blue, transparent);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, blue, transparent);
  background: linear-gradient(left, blue, transparent);
  font-size: 0px;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.bt-menu .bt-menu-trigger span:before, .bt-menu .bt-menu-trigger span:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #adadff;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, blue, transparent);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, blue, transparent);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, blue, transparent);
  background: linear-gradient(left, blue, transparent);
  content: '';
}
.bt-menu .bt-menu-trigger span:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-250%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-250%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-250%);
  transform: translateY(-250%);
}
.bt-menu .bt-menu-trigger span:after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(250%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(250%);
  -o-transform: translateY(250%);
  transform: translateY(250%);
}
.bt-menu.bt-menu-open .bt-menu-trigger span:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0) rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0) rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: translateY(0) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateY(0) rotate(45deg);
}
.bt-menu.bt-menu-open .bt-menu-trigger span:after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
}
.bt-menu.bt-menu-open .bt-menu-trigger span {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav id="bt-menu" class="bt-menu">
  <a href="#" class="bt-menu-trigger"><span></span></a>
</nav>
```

When my attempts above didn't work I started  trying to implement answers to the question linked above. However, these didn't work as I will explain below.

**The Opacity Approach**
This did not work as I used the pseudo elements `:before` and `:after` to create the rotating lines. This meant when using this approach all three lines faded out instead of just the middle one.

**The `background-position` Approach**
This appeared to just not work. I am afraid I have no better explanation to as why.

I would appreciate any help in fixing the fade out on the middle line when it is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there is a simple solution for this example. Make the span transparent, but not the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements. Then add a div which overlays the span. After you have done this you can give the div a desired background gradient and then fade its opacity out. This will leave the span unaffected and provide the desired result.

For example by changing the HTMLto something such as

```
<nav id="bt-menu" class="bt-menu">
    <a href="#" class="bt-menu-trigger"><span><div></div></span></a>
</nav>
```

And the SCSS to something like

```
span {
  background: transparent;

  div {
    @include linear(#adadff, left, blue, transparent);
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

&.bt-menu-open {
  .bt-menu-trigger span {
    div {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Provides this working example

```js
var toggleOpenClose = 0;
var menuButton = $("#bt-menu");

menuButton.click(function() {
  if(toggleOpenClose % 2 == 0) {
    menuButton.removeClass('bt-menu-close').addClass('bt-menu-open');
    menuButton.children(".bt-menu-trigger").children("span").removeClass("close").addClass("open");
  } else {
    menuButton.removeClass('bt-menu-open').addClass('bt-menu-close');
    menuButton.children(".bt-menu-trigger").children("span").removeClass("open").addClass("close");
  }

  toggleOpenClose++;
});

var time = 1;
var timeShortSlide = 0.8;

document.styleSheets[0].addRule(".bt-menu-trigger span div", "transition: opacity " + (timeShortSlide * 0.75) + "s; transition-delay: " + (time - timeShortSlide) + "s;");
document.styleSheets[0].addRule(".bt-menu-trigger span.open:before", "transition: transform " + timeShortSlide + "s; transition-delay: " + (time - timeShortSlide) + "s;");
document.styleSheets[0].addRule(".bt-menu-trigger span.open:after", "transition: transform " + timeShortSlide + "s; transition-delay: " + (time - timeShortSlide) + "s;");
document.styleSheets[0].addRule(".bt-menu-trigger span.close:before", "transition: transform " + timeShortSlide + "s;");
document.styleSheets[0].addRule(".bt-menu-trigger span.close:after", "transition: transform " + timeShortSlide + "s;");
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bt-menu {
  width: 50px;
}
.bt-menu .bt-menu-trigger {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.bt-menu .bt-menu-trigger span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 0px;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.bt-menu .bt-menu-trigger span:before, .bt-menu .bt-menu-trigger span:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #adadff;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, blue, transparent);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, blue, transparent);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, blue, transparent);
  background: linear-gradient(left, blue, transparent);
  content: '';
}
.bt-menu .bt-menu-trigger span:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-250%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-250%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-250%);
  transform: translateY(-250%);
}
.bt-menu .bt-menu-trigger span:after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(250%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(250%);
  -o-transform: translateY(250%);
  transform: translateY(250%);
}
.bt-menu.bt-menu-open .bt-menu-trigger span:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0) rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0) rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: translateY(0) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateY(0) rotate(45deg);
}
.bt-menu.bt-menu-open .bt-menu-trigger span:after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
}
.bt-menu.bt-menu-open .bt-menu-trigger span div {
  opacity: 0;
}
.bt-menu .bt-menu-trigger span div {
  background: #adadff;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, blue, transparent);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, blue, transparent);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, blue, transparent);
  background: linear-gradient(left, blue, transparent);
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav id="bt-menu" class="bt-menu">
  <a href="#" class="bt-menu-trigger"><span><div></div></span></a>
</nav>
```