# How can I set different gradients as background, each time user refreshes?

Tags: javascript, css, css-gradients

I'm working on a bootstrap based webpage and in my CSS file I have the following code:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #3a7bd5; /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #3a7bd5 , #3a6073); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #3a7bd5 , #3a6073); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}
```

it applies gradient as a background to my page, however I have also two other gradients:

```
background: #114357; /* fallback for old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #114357 , #F29492); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to left, #114357 , #F29492); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
```

and

```
background: #eacda3; /* fallback for old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #eacda3 , #d6ae7b); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to left, #eacda3 , #d6ae7b); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
```

and now I want to apply one of those 3 gradients randomly when user refreshes the page (so e.g. first he sees the 2nd gradient, then he refreshes the page and sees the 3rd gradient, etc.).

How can I achieve this effect?

Comment: So add JavaScript to append a random class to the body tag

Comment: Or do it on `server-side` to prevent flickering. But yes, three classes will do it (*or two classes and one default on `body`*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the page loads, add a random class to the `<body>` element using JavaScript, and assign different gradients to different classes.

```js
document.body.classList.add('gradient' + [1, 2, 3][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)])
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body.gradient1 {
  background: #3a7bd5; /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #3a7bd5 , #3a6073); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #3a7bd5 , #3a6073); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}
body.gradient2 {
  background: #114357; /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #114357 , #F29492); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #114357 , #F29492); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */

}
body.gradient3 {
  background: #eacda3; /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #eacda3 , #d6ae7b); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #eacda3 , #d6ae7b); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}
```

Comment: To make sure the flickering isn't that bad, set a default on `#FFF` as background, and apply a transition of 0.1s linear (or whatever you like). Gives it a smooth effect.

Comment: @user3766930 I don't think that's possible, see [Use CSS3 transitions with gradient backgrounds](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6542212/3853934).