# Hover button with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my agency's website, the buttons on the homepage have a small delay between hovering and I don't know what's causing this behaviour. Could you guys take a look?
[Aparticula](https://www.aparticula.com)

This is the code applied to it

```
.btn span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  width: 196px;
  height: 34px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Please help!

Comment: seems fine to me

Comment: Is this really the only transition applied? ... I would check if there is anything other which adds delay to it ... with only this applied it should work as expected

Comment: change `transition: all .5s ease-in-out;` to `transition: all 0s ease-in-out;`

Comment: From the code of your website I can see that you apply a transition on the basic class `.btn` and one at `.btn:hover` with different values for the transition timing ... you should ditch the one at `:hover` to see if the delay persists ... also change `all` to the value you want to change ... it makes the transition faster asd well

Comment: the reason behind that delay Gradients don't support transitions yet . read more from here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542212/use-css3-transitions-with-gradient-backgrounds

Answer (score 3):

That because you have applied `transition` to all 
Remove this from your css

```
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Transition` properties allow elements to change values over a specified duration, animating the property changes, rather than having them occur immediately.

For better understanding, check this out :

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #914969;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
}

.box:hover {
  background-color: #ff9999;
  cursor: pointer;
```

```html
<div class="box">Transition effects</div>
```

For the most part, the order of the values does not matter -- unless a delay is specified. If you specify a delay, you must first specify a duration. The first value that the browser recognizes as a valid time value will always represent the duration. Any subsequent valid time value will be parsed as the delay.

Some properties cannot be transitioned because they are not animatable properties. See the spec for a full list of which properties are [animatable](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transitions-1/#animatable-properties).

Hope this helps..!