# Different hover behaviour for linear gradient backgrounds on divs

Tags: html, css

I have two div's for two different buttons. The only thing that changes between the two div's is that one has a `background: #E82171;` whereas another has a gradient `background: linear-gradient(to right, #e82171 , #ef3e36);`.

However, I want to understand why they both have different hover behaviour even though they both have the same styling?

```css
body{
  background-color: blue;
}

/** BUTTON 1 **/ 

.formLink {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #e82171 , #ef3e36);
    padding: 24px 40px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    transition: all 0.6s;
    outline:none;
    }
    
.formLink:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ffffff;
    background: #404262;
}


/** BUTTON 2 **/ 

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.6s;
    color: #ffffff;
    outline: none;
    background: #E82171;
    font-size: 90%;
}
.btn:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ffffff;
    background: #404262;
}
```

```html
<div class="formLink">Button 1</div>

<div class="btn">Button 2</div>
```

As you can see, hovering on `button 1` is much more *instant*. I basically want `button 1` to have a slow transition on hover, like in `button 2`.

For testing, I changed the linear gradient to `background: #E82171;` for `button 1` and the transition works exactly how I want it. Unsure why linear gradient will effect this?

**Edit**:

After finding out there's no "direct" way to do this, I decided to find a workaround based off [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542212/use-css3-transitions-with-gradient-backgrounds).

```css
body{
  background-color: blue;
}
.formLink {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    background: linear-gradient(to right,#e82171,#ef3e36);
    padding: 24px 40px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 900;
    transition: all .6s;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(to right,#e82171,#ef3e36);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right,#e82171,#ef3e36);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(to right,#e82171,#ef3e36);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #e82171, #ef3e36);
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
      background-repeat: repeat-y;
      background-size: 100%;
      background-position: 0 100% no-repeat;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.6s linear;
         -moz-transition: all 0.6s linear;
           -o-transition: all 0.6s linear;
              transition: all 0.6s linear;
}

.formLink:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff;
    background: #404262;
    background-position: 0 0;
}


/*************/

/** BUTTON 2 **/ 

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.6s;
    color: #ffffff;
    outline: none;
    background: #E82171;
    font-size: 90%;
}
.btn:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ffffff;
    background: #404262;
}
```

```html
<div class="formLink">Download</div>
<div class="btn">Button 2</div>
```

I think my *download* button is nearly the same as *button 2*? You guys can advice better. However, I'm not sure why my *download* button "blinks" when hovering over it? The background disappears for a second and then reappears? Ideas on why? I need it to function exactly like *button 2*.

Comment: seems like its not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542212/use-css3-transitions-with-gradient-backgrounds

Comment: If you are willing to use js, you could emulate the behaviour: https://opticalcortex.com/animating-css-gradients/ However, there does not seem to be a css only way.

Comment: @Sirence - I'd rather avoid the use of JS. I've attempted to workaround the issue based on a previous solution. I've updated my question to reflect my current approach. Maybe you could help?

Comment: Your button blinks because you are chaning the solid red background to a transparent one with the opacity animation - the only way to avoid this is to position a copy of the button without animation behind it, and put the animated one over it. I'll post the code below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the blinking behaviour, you need to use a copy of the button behind it - otherwise the background will be transparent during the opacity animation. You do not have to use a second div, you can use the pseudo element after instead:

https://jsfiddle.net/qLmpxgd8/2/

```css
body{
  background-color: blue;
}

.formLink, .formLink:after {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    background: linear-gradient(to right,#e82171,#ef3e36);
    padding: 24px 40px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 900;
    transition: all .6s;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(to right,#e82171,#ef3e36);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right,#e82171,#ef3e36);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(to right,#e82171,#ef3e36);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e82171, #ef3e36);
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
      background-repeat: repeat-y;
      background-size: 100%;
      background-position: 0 100% no-repeat;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.6s linear;
         -moz-transition: all 0.6s linear;
           -o-transition: all 0.6s linear;
              transition: all 0.6s linear;
}

.formLink:after {
  content: "Download";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.formLink:hover:after {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff;
    background: #404262;
    background-position: 0 0;
}


/*************/

/** BUTTON 2 **/ 

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.6s;
    color: #ffffff;
    outline: none;
    background: #E82171;
    font-size: 90%;
}
.btn:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ffffff;
    background: #404262;
}
```

```html
<div class="formLink">Download</div>
<div class="btn">Button 2</div>
```

Comment: Hover effect work exactly how I want it! Cheers! I was looking to maybe add an arrow icon to a few of these buttons, but unsure on how I can make the icon display before and after hover? I.e. https://jsfiddle.net/8fbytp3e/25/ - getting the text and arrow in 'formLink' to appear as is on 'btn'? You've already answered my original question, so let me know if it's best to open a new question for this.

Comment: An easy solution would be to use a second div instead of the :after - simply a copy of the first button, with the text and the arrow image inside it. You will need to position it exactly like the first button. If you want to open a second question, I will adjust the fiddle for you once I return from my lunch break (unless somebody else posts first).

Comment: @Freddy: here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/8fbytp3e/31/ Just replaced the after with a new div, with the same content as the parent div.

Comment: Legend! Cheers for your help and also for explaining everything!

Comment: You are very welcome! I just saw my button in the linked fiddle was too big though, just remove the `height: 100%` and `width: 100%`: https://jsfiddle.net/8fbytp3e/33/