# Text overflow gradient - transition is not smooth when hover is off

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a dropdown where the overflow text is gradient out. There's transition applied to the selection's wrapper but now it looks a bit odd when it's hovered out. How can I make it look better?

html snippet:

```
<div class="durationDropdown">
  <select role="listbox" class="durationSelect">
   <option value="0">Less than 1 month</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

css snippet:

```
.container {
  width: 150px;
}

.durationDropdown {
  padding: 0px;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 5.1875rem;
  transition: 250ms;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

.durationDropdown::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  top: 0%;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 63%);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.durationDropdown:hover::after,
.durationDropdown:active::after {
  background: none;
}

.durationDropdown:hover {
  background: black;
}
```

Here's my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ywohg589/2/) where you can see how it looks like and the rest of the css in the fiddle. Any help/suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cannot add transition to the gradient, see details here [Use CSS3 transitions with gradient backgrounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542212/use-css3-transitions-with-gradient-backgrounds).

What you really see it's smooth changing of the 'color' property but not the gradient transition. If you want to hide a part of the sentence with a gradient and have a smooth transition on it, you could do like so:

- Add transition to 'durationDropdown::after' element and replace 'background: none;' by 'opacity: 0;' like so:

```
.durationDropdown::after {
  ...
  transition: 250ms opacity ease-in-out;
  ...
}

.durationDropdown:hover::after,
.durationDropdown:active::after {
  /* background: none; */
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried that but it doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: @RH1922 try to increase transition time, if it's not noticeable. See example here https://jsfiddle.net/sfmncov8/4/ . I removed color changing on hover for selected item, just to see the transition.