# How to put transition on background (color to radial-gradient)

Tags: css

I have an element with background set as color

On hover background is set as `radial-gradient`

I want to make transition between colors on hover but it creates weird effect where my element disappear for a second.

Here is link

[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/a9cqme1y/)

Is it possible to switch between color and gradient without this problem?

```
.link {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20%;
  padding: 0 25px;
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 42px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: radial-gradient(98px 98px at center center, red 0%, #0088b5 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with background-size:

```css
.link {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 25px;
  line-height: 42px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle,red 0%, #0088b5 100%);
  background-position:center;
  background-size:600% 600%; /*a big size to see only the red*/
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.link:hover {
  background-size:150% 150%; /* reduce the size to see the gadient effect*/
}
```

```html
<div class="link">Link</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:before` pseudo-element along with a transition on the opacity of the background color to get this effect.

Credit: [Dave Lunny](https://medium.com/@dave_lunny/animating-css-gradients-using-only-css-d2fd7671e759).

Also, check out [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542212/use-css3-transitions-with-gradient-backgrounds/51238406#51238406).

```css
.link {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20%;
  padding: 0 25px;
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 42px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.link:before {
  border-radius: inherit;
  content: '';    
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -100;
  background: radial-gradient(98px 98px at center center, red 0%, #0088b5 100%);
}

.link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="#">Hover Me!</a>
```