# How to make it work for transtion-duration at paticular classes in html tables

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I would like to change classes in html tables in certain `transition-duration`.

I defined `hospitalization` and `hospitalization2` classes

In terms of `hospitalization`, `transition-duration` didn't work well.   On the other hand, in `hospitalization2`, it works well.

Why `transition-duration` didn't work in `hospitalization` and how to fix it?

Thanks

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("hospitalization");
  });
});
```

```css
.hospitalization {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, aqua 49%,aqua 1%, yellow 1%, yellow 50%);
  transition-duration:0.4s;
}

.hospitalization2 {
  background-color:red;
  transition-duration:0.4s;
}

td {
  padding: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td id="1">1</td>
  <td id="2">2</td>
  <td id="3">3</td>
  <td id="4">4</td>
  <td id="5">5</td>
  <td id="6">6</td>
  <td id="7">7</td>
  <td id="8">8</td>
  <td id="9">9</td>
  <td id="10">10</td>
</table>
```

Comment: Does this answer helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542212/use-css3-transitions-with-gradient-backgrounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transition doesn't work for `background: linear-gradient()`. You can use `background-size` or `background-position` if you want to create some effect with it.

A solution would be to use a pseudo-element, like `:before`, to create the transition effect. In addition, add a span to wrap each text, then you can add `z-index` for the text to be in front of the pseudo-element.

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("hospitalization");
  });
});
```

```css
.hospitalization2 {
  background-color:red;
  transition-duration:0.4s;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

td span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

td:before {
  content: '';
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, aqua 49%,aqua 1%, yellow 1%, yellow 50%);
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
  width: 100%;
}

td.hospitalization:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td id="1"><span>1</span></td>
  <td id="2"><span>2</span></td>
  <td id="3"><span>3</span></td>
  <td id="4"><span>4</span></td>
  <td id="5"><span>5</span></td>
  <td id="6"><span>6</span></td>
  <td id="7"><span>7</span></td>
  <td id="8"><span>8</span></td>
  <td id="9"><span>9</span></td>
  <td id="10"><span>10</span></td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

you cant add transition to gradient colors, not supported