# Animate Angular Dynamic Progress Bar Gradient With Color Stops

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm writing a custom progress bar using gradients and color stops.

See example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-progress-bar-gradient

The problem I'm trying to fix is the animation is very "jumpy". I want to animate the progress bar so it fills smooth and gradually instead of instantly jumping to the new position.

I tried adding `transition: all 0.4s ease-in;` to my button but that does not seem to effect the gradient at all.

Component.ts

```
import { Component, VERSION } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;
  progressStyle = "#18191C";

  constructor() {
    const me = this;

    let perc = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
      me.progressStyle = `linear-gradient(90deg, #8354C1 ${perc}%, #18191C ${perc}%)`;
      perc += 5;
      if (perc >= 100) {
        perc = 0;
      }
    }, 300);
  }
}
```

Component.html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary launch-btn" [style.background]="progressStyle">
  Testing
</button>
```

Component.css

```
.btn {
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.btn[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}
.btn.launch-btn {
  border: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
  width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: you repeated the same question twice, delete one of them

Answer (score 0):

[Gradients don't support transition.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6542623/11151040)

Why not increase the resolution? So you can get the behavior you want.

[Demo](https://angular-progress-bar-gradient-aofulh-2.stackblitz.io/),
[Project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-progress-bar-gradient-aofulh-2)

Comment: Two reasons, one being the percentage is sent from another application over a websocket. With higher resolutions the amount of calls increase by orders of magnitude. Second being, your demo jumps for me as well.

Comment: Then you will have to deal with this in other ways. For example the `<button>` element may have a different floating element inside. You can "`transition`" the incoming amount by changing the "`width`" value of that element.

Comment: Yeah I'm going to try using another div which just grows in width. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I can suggest the following to speed up your works: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/progress/#labels It contains  `.progress-bar` in `.progress` element.