# Tailwind background gradient transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

Does Tailwind CSS allow transitions of gradients i.e. changing the *'from'* or *'to'* color so that the gradient of either color changes by a transition?

What I have tried:

```
<button class="transition duration-500 ease-in-out bg-gradient-to-t from-black to-white hover:to-red-500">
    Hover me
</button>
```

Comment: From solid to gradient, you can add an absolute div on top with solid background that turns into transparent with a transition, so the one behind with gradient will appear slowly :)

Comment: @FrancoMéndez That's exactly the solution I went for and the result is visually beautiful. If you create a more detailed post with a sandbox link (I personally used React to make this work), I'll mark it as a selected answer.

Comment: You clearly stated that you needed the gradient itself to transition, so please either update your original question to be more concise or answer it yourself to help the thousands of people that find this thread.

Answer (score 30):

As chojinicki already pointed out, it is not possible without any workarounds, especially without adding extensions to your config file. Because I needed the exact same for my project, I created my own workaround for it.

You have to double the background size of the element and transition the background position using `transition-all` to get the desired effect. Note that you require the `via-` gradient stop.

Tailwind Play: https://play.tailwindcss.com/XFQDCOKQ8L

```html
<button className="transition-all duration-500 bg-gradient-to-t to-white via-black from-red-500 bg-size-200 bg-pos-0 hover:bg-pos-100">
    Hover me
</button>
```

tailwind.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    // ...
    theme: {
        extend: {
            backgroundSize: {
                'size-200': '200% 200%',
            },
            backgroundPosition: {
                'pos-0': '0% 0%',
                'pos-100': '100% 100%',
            },
        },
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, it is very limited and doesn't exactly work with your exact example provided, however this is the closest you can get.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of the possible implementations with [CSS @property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@property), following chojnicki's advice.

The implementation borrows code at large from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63848864/18943813).

First you define the properties with their initial value, then associate it with a class, where you will configure both the gradient and the transition. After that you should configure another style for this class with the hover selector appended to it, changing the defined colors.

```css
@layer utilities {
  @property --myColor1 {
    syntax: '<color>';
    initial-value: theme(colors.cyan.500);
    inherits: false;
  }

  @property --myColor2 {
    syntax: '<color>';
    initial-value: theme(colors.emerald.500);
    inherits: false;
  }

  .my-button {
    background: linear-gradient(var(--myColor1), var(--myColor2));
    transition:
      --myColor1 0.5s ease-in-out,
      --myColor2 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }

  .my-button:hover {
    --myColor1: theme(colors.orange.500);
    --myColor2: theme(colors.yellow.500);
  }
}
```

Then you just have to reference the class.

```html
<button class="my-button">
    Hover me
</button>
```

Note: The properties and classes were defined under `@layer utilities` to express intention and to gain precedence over other classes. You can find more about it [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-css-and-layer).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer **No**, but not because of lack this functionality in Tailwind but rather in CSS itself. Reason for that is probably performance issues - browser engine would have to render separate gradient for every frame of animation.

This is common question: [Use CSS3 transitions with gradient backgrounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542212/use-css3-transitions-with-gradient-backgrounds)

You can only try to use some workaround (depends what exactly effect you expect) like background position, opacity etc (examples in linked question and plenty tutorials online). If something works for you - just extract this as Tailwind utility if you need this in multiple places.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-new-utilities