# Div Button hover: transition linear gradient

Tags: html, css, animation

Hello I have a div with  tag and  tag inside to create a button like this :

https://media.giphy.com/media/LXBvjTlqqPZNxB0Mtr/giphy.gif

However I am not getting the linear-gradient css hover transition effect that I want:
like this :
https://media.giphy.com/media/Db7n9RI9a6OrLh2XlP/giphy.gif

this is how my html skeleton looks liek :

```
<div class="address-btn">
            <a href="#">Copy Address</a>
            <i class="fas fa-wallet"></i>
          </div>
```

and this is my css for it

```
.address-btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #2393ff 0%, #5f01ff 100%);
  border-radius: 3px;
  a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
  }



  &:hover {
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #5f01ff 0%, #2393ff 100%);
  }
```

why am i not getting the same effect as the correct one?

Comment: that didnt change anything.. my transition is too quick idk why

Comment: sorry i thought you were trying to let it like the first gif

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use CSS3 transitions with gradient backgrounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542212/use-css3-transitions-with-gradient-backgrounds)

Answer (score 0):

Everything work fine. You missed `}` andd.. look this

```css
.address-btn{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px 5px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px;
    color: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #2393ff 0%, #5f01ff 100%);
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.address-btn:hover{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #5f01ff 0%, #2393ff 100%);
}

a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="address-btn">
    <a href="#">Copy Address</a>
</div>
```