# gradient color transition on hover

Tags: colors, transition, gradient

the gradient color on hover was change immediately. I wanna add transition before changing to the color just like span-2.
Is there any solution to make like this?

dont mind me if my english is not good.

check code here ------>https://jsfiddle.net/zv7mkg1r/8/

Comment: You could possibly use keyframes for this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542212/use-css3-transitions-with-gradient-backgrounds