# unable to transition from static background color to gradient, animation background

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
body {
  background: var(--main-color);
  transition: background 200ms ease;
  &.page-body {
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;

    @keyframes gradient {
      0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
      }
      50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
      }
      100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When the `body` is added the `page-body` class, then the background should transition from the static color of `var(--main-color)` to the gradient animation defined in the `page-body` class.

But it doesn't work. How to get it to work?

Comment: why isn't the animation working then?

Comment: You can use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63848864/3702797 and set your initial value to the same linear-gradient(...var(--color-1)etc.