# Transitioning between a background color and a background gradient

Tags: javascript, css

I have a nice effect where I transition between colours on the body element of a website, based on a data-color attribute set on a div as I scroll through the site.

If I use regular colours, all's good. But now I want to use a linear gradient and this does not work at all.

Instead of a smooth transition with a delay, it 'jumps' straight in.

Now the solution I'm thinking of is to keep the div with the gradient, then have another div on top of that which inherits the colour from the body and then fade that out to reveal the gradient.

The content would also have to sit in another div, on top of both of these.

However, this might not be the most elegant solution.

All suggestions are welcome.

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-color]');

document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  sections.forEach((o) => {
    o.getBoundingClientRect().top <= document.body.scrollTop + 100 && (document.body.setAttribute("class", ""), document.body.classList.add(o.dataset.color));
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  transition: background 1s ease-out;
}

div {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

.primary {
  background: green;
}

.secondary {
  background: red;
}

.tertiary {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, orange 0%, blue 100%);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div data-color="primary"></div>
  <div data-color="secondary"></div>
  <div data-color="tertiary"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: There are many potential solutions on the linked duplicate. I suspect [custom properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63848864/1264804) might suit you best.

Comment: Thanks very much for sharing this isherwood. Exactly what I was after!