# Question about a specific gradient with css3

Tags: css, background, gradient

I am not sure how to exactly phrase this question so maybe that's why I can't find help with this.

I am coding a webpage and the designer has made a background for a part of it. It's sort of a two way gradient: both horizontal and vertical at the same time. I am attaching the image here because I'm not sure how to explain it.

I'm sorry if it's very obvious but I can't find anything resembling this anywhere. Thank you!
Here's the image:
[image: two-way gradient]

EDIT: The question is, can I make this background using just CSS3?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is. You never ask one.

Comment: I just edited the post. Thanks MrDanA, I try so hard not to ask stuff that when I actually do I forget to post the real question =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you able to limit browser support to browsers that support multiple backgrounds?

If so, you can create two gradients, along with a border, to simulate that.

Here's a version that only works in **Firefox**: http://pastehtml.com/view/b295elnso.html

You can modify the webkit and other lines to get it working in other browsers.  I used [the Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to build the lower gradient.

Here's a [good listing of multiple background support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds).

*(Edit: I meant only works in Firefox, not IE.  Doh!)*
*(Edit2: Added multiple background support listing)*

Comment: I didn't know you could use multiple backgrounds. Browser support is not a big deal since it doesn't really matter that much if I get a plain background in a different browser. Thanks a lot!!