# change the background color in CSS3

Tags: css, html, colors, colorbox

I have the following :

```
#box1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow:  -3px 8px 34px  #808080;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: -8px 5px 5px #888888;
    right: 100px; top:  50px;
    height:  300px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#E0FFFF), to(#ADD8E6));
    -webkit-animation-name:myfirst;
    -webkit-animation-duration:5s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction:alternate;
    -webkit-animation-play-state:running;
}

 @-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
from {background:red;}
to {background:yellow;}
}
```

My question is: in those lines

```
from {background:red;}
    to {background:yellow;}
```

how can I change the start color (red) to this (in the next line) will be like this color in the background:

```
 -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#E0FFFF), to(#ADD8E6));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654510/css3-animation-with-gradients

Comment: a gradient is a background-image, not a background-color. How do you want to make a transition between two different kinds of attributes?

Comment: I mean that this "from(#E0FFFF), to(#ADD8E6)" will be the start color, and yellow will be in the end. Can I do it?

Comment: do you mean stop the loop. that is end the animation with yellow.

Comment: Yes, and the *start* color will be more than one color like this 
----from(#E0FFFF), to(#ADD8E6));-----

Comment: thank you it works! but what this is mean "#box1 > div"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code.

**Note** : it's possible when you use sub div...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>What</title>
<style type="text/css">
#box1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow:  -3px 8px 34px  #808080;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: -8px 5px 5px #888888;
    right: 100px; top:  50px;
    height:  300px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#E0FFFF), to(#ADD8E6));
}

#box1 > div
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation:myfirst 5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="box1"><div></div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't understand what you did here (can you explain pleas?) and this code is not working for me...