# CSS3 animation color with gradient

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I´m using CSS3 animation to turn one bootstrap accordion from one color no other, but the problem is that I see that is not possible with animation to do that transition with gradient, and the accordion seems too much 2D too me.
I read that people do some tricks like putting one element one over the other and using the opacity, but in may case is not so easy set another element in the same position since is create dynamically.

Can you give me any suggestion tip please?

Here is what I try to do without success so far:

```
.panel-warning > .panel-heading {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FCFCFC 0%, #FFF4C4 30%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 0;
}

.panel-warning > .panel-heading {
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-name: alert-warning;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
    -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-name: alert-warning;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle demo?

Comment: Sorry but is very complicated since the HTML is create by JSP dynamically.

Comment: A minimal example showing the problem and the intended result would help us understand your requirements

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with the others that it's not clear what exactly you wish to accomplish, here's some demo code for simple animation of gradients:

```
.two:link, .two:visited {
  background: #2876b2;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#2876b2, #549ad0);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#2876b2, #549ad0);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#2876b2, #549ad0);
  background: linear-gradient(#2876b2, #549ad0);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 200%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .5s linear;
  -o-transition: all .5s linear;
  transition: all .5s linear;
}

.two:hover, .two:focus, .two:active {
  background-position: 0 -102%;
}
```

This applies to a button and is taken from [here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/animating-css3-gradients/).

If you're after something much more complicated, you're probably going to need some sophisticated JavaScript hackery.

Comment: Here you´re just moving the gradient. What I´m doing is a loop to move an animation from one color to another. I saw this demo yesterday. Thanks anywau

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want a css3 gradient animation, so if you use the search in this site, you can find this issue which contains a possible solution to your question:

[css3-animation-with-gradients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654510/css3-animation-with-gradients)

my favourite solution is Brian's http://jsfiddle.net/jSsZn/
`CSS3`

Comment: I think use that technique in my case would be complicated, but thanks!